# add product to cart in woocomerce on product page created by elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i have follow code and cant get product to cart whats wrong:
This is my code: api respones but can get product to cart: il get wel: alert("Product " + sku + " has been added to the cart."); but not to cart

`'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// When the "Add to Cart" button is clicked
$('button[name="add-to-cart"]').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of the button (if present)

```
    // Find the element with the class "sku" and get the text value
    var sku = $('.sku').text().trim(); // Get the SKU value

    // The XML data you want to send
    var xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
        '<inforequest creationDateTime="' + new Date().toISOString() + '">' +
        '<identification>' +
        '<customerid>041329</customerid>' +
        '</identification>' +
        '<infodetails>' +
        '<lineId>001</lineId>' +
        '<productId>' + sku + '</productId>' +
        '<infoquantity>4</infoquantity>' +
        '</infodetails>' +
        '</inforequest>';

    console.log("Request XML data:", xmlData); // Debug output

    // Perform an AJAX request to the server-side proxy with the XML data
    $.ajax({
        url: "/proxy.php", // Adjust the path to the actual path on your server
        type: "POST",
        data: xmlData,
        contentType: "text/xml", // Ensure the correct content type is set
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(response) {
            // Process the API response here and take actions based on the inventory status.
            console.log("API response:", response); // Debug output

            // Add the rest of your code to handle the API response

            // Check if the product should be added to the cart
            var infodetails = $(response).find('infodetails');

            if (infodetails.length > 0) {
                // Element <infodetails> found, add item to the cart
                alert("Product " + sku + " has been added to the cart.");
            } else {
                // Element <infodetails> not found, display a message
                alert("This item cannot be added to the cart.");
            }

            // Enable the "Add to Cart" button
            $('button[name="add-to-cart"]').prop('disabled', false);

            // Enable the "View Cart" hyperlink
            $('a.added_to_cart.wc-forward').off('click'); // Remove the click behavior prevention
        },
        error: function() {
            // Display an error message if the API request fails
            alert("Error retrieving inventory information.");

            // Disable the "Add to Cart" button
            $('button[name="add-to-cart"]').prop('disabled', true);

            // Enable the "View Cart" hyperlink
            $('a.added_to_cart.wc-forward').off('click'); // Remove the click behavior prevention
        }
    });
});
```

});
`

Comment: What's the response that you're console logging in success callback?